# How to get value of data-id and place it into a twitter bootstrap modal?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Im trying to get the value of the data-id which contains and id in my database. I need to get the admin_id and place it into a twitter bootstrap modal. How am I going to get that value using java script?

```
<a data-toggle="modal" data-id="<?=$row['ADMIN_ID'];?>" href="#view_contact" class="btn btn-info btn-xs view-admin">View</a>
```

here is my modal

```
            <div class="modal fade" id="view_contact" role="dialog">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                    <div class="modal-content">

                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <h4>Admin modal!!</h4>

                        </div>

                        <div class="modal-body">
                            Admin Id:<p id="showid"></p>
                        </div>

                        <div class="modal-footer">

                            <a class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>

                        </div>


                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>
```

here is my java script

```
            <script type="text/javascript">


            $(document).on("click", ".view-admin", function () {
                 var adminid = $(this).data('id');
                 $(".modal-body #showid").val( adminid );
                 $('#view_contact').modal('show');
            });

            </script>
```

its not showing in my modal. They are all in the same page. How do I do this? Kinda new at this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is, you are trying to assign the value to a `p` tag. `p` tag does not have value property. Use `text()` or `html()`

```
$(document).on("click", ".view-admin", function() {
    var adminid = $(this).data('id');
    $(".modal-body #showid").text(adminid);
    $('#view_contact').modal('show');
});
```

Comment: This works, thanks a lot! But how about if I want to echo the variable in the modal for example: <?php echo $adminid; ?> and not assigning the value to a <p> tag?

Answer (score 0):

You can just replace

```
$(".modal-body #showid").val( adminid );
```

with

```
$("#showid").text( adminid );
```

You don't need to reference class name `.modal-body` for the id `#showid` as there must be only one id name in a page according to [W3C Validation](http://validator.w3.org/). And referencing with the id is the fastest way to access any html elements.