# How to get id of specific record when click on image

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

This is my view

```
<tbody>
    @{ int index = 0;}
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        index = index + 1;
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" id="@*@item.CustId*@" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-target="#custtransfermodel" data-toggle="modal">
                    <img src="~/Images/appimg/transfer.png" class="custid" alt="" id ="@item.CustId" />
                </a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="EditCustomer(@item.CustId)">
                    <img src="~/Images/appimg/edit.png" alt="" />
                </a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="javascript:void(0)"   onclick="DeleteCustomer(@item.CustId)">
                    <img src="~/Images/appimg/delete.png" alt="" />
                </a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="" onclick="viewDetail()">
                    <img src="~/Images/appimg/view_detail.png" />    
                </a>
            </td>
            <td>
                @if (item.Flag == false)
                { 
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="@item.CustId" class="flag" onclick="flagCustomer('false',this.id)">
                        <img src="~/Images/appimg/star.png" alt="" />
                    </a>
                }
                else
                {   
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="flag" id="@item.CustId" onclick="flagCustomer('true',this.id)">
                        <img src="~/Images/appimg/MapMarker_Flag.png" />
                    </a>
                }
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CustFirstName)
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CustMiddleName)
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CustLastName)
            </td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CentreName) </td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PhoneNumber)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Email) </td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EmployeeName) </td>
        </tr>
    }
</tbody>
```

This is my controller code

```
[HttpPost]
public int TransferCustomer(int _empId, int _custId)
{
    Customer customer = new Customer();
    // int _result=0;
    customer.CustId=Convert.ToInt32(_custId);
    customer.CreatedBy = Convert.ToInt32(_empId);
    var result = customerBal.TransferCustomertoEmployee(customer);
    return result;    
}
```

Also you can see my view image

[image]

This image is indicate my view. When I click on transfer image it shows me one partial view below see the partial view image.

[image]

This is my partial view. When I click on transfer button my AJAX call is calling first one. My question is when I click on transfer button how can I get employee id and customer id? In first image is my customer list and in second image drop down is employee list. What is wrong in my code?

** This is my Ajax call on button transfer **

```js
$(document).on('click', '#btnTrasnfer', function () {
        debugger;
        
         var empid = $('#CreatedBy').val();
        var custid = $('.custid').attr('id');
        debugger;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "@Url.Action("TransferCustomer", "Customer")",
            data: { _empId: empid, _custId: custid },
            success: function (data) {
                if (data === "1") {
                    notif({
                        msg: "<b>Employee Transfer sucessfully.",
                        type: "success"
                    });
                } else {
                    notif({
                        msg: "<b>error while Transfer Customer.",
                        type: "error"
                    });
                }

            },
            error: function () {
            }
        });
        debugger;

    });
```

Comment: Please take the time to format your question properly. It was completely unreadable before I edited it. If you have a clear question it makes it much easier for someone to read and understand and means you will get a much quicker and more accurate answer.

Comment: My Ajax call is not showing here

Comment: I have only edited the code you placed in the question, nothing has been removed. If there was something missing please edit the question to include it.

Comment: added already but  not showing. I am new on stack overflow please tell me how can i add my ajax call

Comment: Use the `edit` link at the bottom of the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can subscribe to the click event of the elements with the class custid and add an "active" class or similar, like so.

```
$(".custid").on("click",function(){
   $(this).addClass("active");
});
```

Then in the transfer click, you can use this line to get the id

```
$(".custid.active:first").attr("id");
```

Then when everything is compete and modal closes, you can remove the active class.

```
$(".custid.active").removeClass("active");
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not clear what you specifically want.
But as per my understanding you are asking for something like following:

[How to get value of data-id and place it into a twitter bootstrap modal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25861452/how-to-get-value-of-data-id-and-place-it-into-a-twitter-bootstrap-modal)

Comment: KinjalB see....    first image is indicate my customer list and my second image is showing drop down list . drop down list indicate my employee list. when i click on transfer button. then ajax call is calling and only i want that two values... first is custid and second is employee id

Comment: Can you provide me code for showing this transfer partial? So that I can modify it.